# Spring-Batch: Writing objects to lines with fixed length?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

Spring-Batch provides the class `FixedLengthTokenizer` which makes it easy to read different offsets of a single line into the fileds of an object. Whereby the content of each field is extracted from certain ranges with fixed length:

```
FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
String[] names = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
tokenizer.setNames(names);
Range[] ranges = {new Range(1, 4), new Range(5, 12), new Range(13, 14), new Range(15, 15)};
tokenizer.setColumns(ranges);
```

I want to do the exact oposite. I want to write an Object into a flat file whereby the different fields should be written into the file with fixed lengths. Spring-Batch provides the interface `org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.LineAggregator` for mapping lines to objects. But I'm wondering why there is no `FixedLengthLineAggregator` for doing that?

What's the right way in Spring-Batch to write objects to lines whereby the fields have a fixed length?

Comment: Maybe you can use Formatter. Something like this `<beans:property name="format" value="%-8.8s%-12.12s%-11.11s%-16.16s" /> `mean that a you are writing 4 columns to a fixed format file with column lengths as 8, 12, 11 and 16 respectively.

Comment: Yes, there is also an aggregator for that: `org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.FormatterLineAggregator` but I was just wondering if there is no aggregator that allows to work with `Range`'s like `FixedLengthTokenizer `. When writing bigger objects, your format sting proposal would not be so clear and readable.

Comment: I think that you only can do it with this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#fixedWidthFileWritingExample

Comment: Create your own writer which wraps `FlatFileItemWriter` and build the formatter string based on range objects. Shouldn't be that hard?

Comment: We'd be open to a contribution that adds the range way of building a line but as others have pointed out, it does not exist today.

Comment: i am having the same requirement . does spring batch 4 support fixed length file writing @MichaelMinella

Answer (score 0):

As @canillas noted in their comment, the way to manage this would be via Spring Batch's `FormatterLineAggregator`. Using the format capabilities of `String.format` can allow you to generate fixed length records in a way that is standard across the JVM and framework independent.