# Spring batch write to fixed length file in multi line

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I need to write to fixed length file in multiline. Example output should look something like

```
START000201706151038ABC0001                                                  
00A0123456788 20007100000000000000000050                                
00B1                                                                      
00C0                                                                      
00D000000000000000                                             0000       
00A0323456788 20007100000000000000000050                                
00B1                                                                      
00C0                                                                      
00D000000000000000                                             0000       
END00000000490000000000003670406000000000307845636
```

Start is the header and End is the trailer for the file. Each item will have four line , from example above 00A,00B,00C,00D represents four lines each item. is there any writer in spring batch which supports this?. this Question: [Spring-Batch: Writing objects to lines with fixed length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47325636/spring-batch-writing-objects-to-lines-with-fixed-length) is about same need, but there was no answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any writer in spring batch which supports this?

You are writing to a flat file, so you need a `FlatFileItemWriter`. Now how each line (aka each item) is aggregated is dictated by the `LineAggregator`. So it is not a writer that you are looking for, it is rather the `LineAggregator` interface.

As of the latest Spring Batch 4.2.4 , there is  no built-in line aggregator to do that. You need a custom one for your needs.

Comment: I tried creating custom aggregator  and that works well. I used FooterCallBack and headerCallback, but this callback create new line. is it default behaviour?

Comment: i found it its because of DEFAULT_LINE_SEPARATOR in AbstractFileItemWriter

Comment: Please note that accepting an answer is different from upvoting it.